# Paypal access error

Tags: paypal

I am trying to set up the link to my business Paypal account from my web site. I have done this before (successfully) with other accounts for clients, and am using similar code, but I get a page with the following URL:

https://www.paypal.com/webapps/shoppingcart/error?flowlogging_id=421ad74f76dbc&code=INTERNAL_ERROR&mfid=1491998876678_c884608091ec

and a non-descript error message. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? As far as I know the account is correctly set up and the email address is validated. I have tried using different browsers, but they are all fairly old (but as up-to-date as my MacOS 10.6.8 supports).

Thank you

Geoff

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the business variable with an incorrect value, hence PayPal gave an error message. Pass the business variable from your website with your PayPal account email address. then you won't get an error message. Refer the below:

```
<input type="hidden" name="business" value=" addyour PayPal account email address">
```